# Speech Synthesizer "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Here is my code:

```
string _message = "Hello world.";
SpeechSynthesizer _synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
Prompt _prompt = new Prompt(_message);
_synth.Speak(_prompt);
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what exactly is causing this error:

"Input string was not in a correct format."

The line that causes this error is when I call `_synth.Speak(_prompt);`

EDIT: I have tried this code on my desktop computer and it works fine so something is wrong with my install on my laptop. Still I'm not too sure how to fix this...

EDIT:

The stacktrace:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffe
r& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo in
fo)
   at System.Speech.Internal.SapiAttributeParser.GetCultureInfoFromLanguageStrin
g(String valueString)
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceInfo..ctor(VoiceObjectToken token)
   at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.BuildInstalledVoices(Voice
Synthesis voiceSynthesizer)
   at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis..ctor(WeakReference speech
Synthesizer)
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_VoiceSynthesizer()
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.Speak(Prompt prompt)
   at TTSTesting.Program.Speak(String _message) in C:\Users\ctanaka\Desktop\TTST
esting\TTSTesting\Program.cs:line 22
```

Comment: As a side note I have tried this exact code on my other pc and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Any documentation on that method?

Comment: This is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586905.aspx right?

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  Are you sure it's from that code block?

Comment: @MrLister yes I am using that library.

Comment: @recursive It is the last line where I actually call the Speech Synthesizer to speak: _synth.Speak(_prompt);

Comment: Can you copy the callstack of the exception? That might show that the error occurred inside the library. Honestly it doesn't look like this code is the issue.

Comment: I've seen this error reported once before.  At least in that case the programmer tried to make a Polish machine speak English.  Anything similar?  He didn't post a stack trace either so impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @Adam - Yes I believe it is a library issue. I was messing with other text to speech engines and had to install a few things... this might be the cause. I uninstalled the other engines but still no luck. Is there any way to reinstall the original library?

Comment: @HansPassant - Yes I believe it is a library issue. I was messing with other text to speech engines and had to install a few things... this might be the cause. I uninstalled the other engines but still no luck. Is there any way to reinstall the original library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry of your machine is messed up, it contains invalid voice configuration data.  The relevant key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens`.  Underneath, you'll find the installed voices.  An English machine typically has MS-Anna there but there can be others if you purchased more.

The messed up value is Attribute\Language, it isn't an hexadecimal number like it should be.  Like "409", the hex value of the LCID for English.

You might fix it by uninstalling voices you added, deleting bad voices in the registry or fixing the Language value.  Reinstalling is tricky, this is part of the Windows setup on Vista and up.  You'll need help from superuser.com if you can't get it fixed.  Or your setup DVD.

Comment: I checked the registry value for the language and it seems to already be set to 409. Also the text to speech preview in windows 7 speech properties works, so maybe the library .dll is messed up?

Comment: It is a framework assembly, you'd have to work really hard to mess that up.  Check *all* of the voices listed, not just the first one.  Use SysInternal's ProcMon tool to see the framework code reading the registry.  There are possible complications on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: The only voice listed in the registry is MS Anna. How exactly do I see the framework code reading the registry using ProcMon?

Comment: You were right I found that I actually had some Loquendo TTS software installed. After uninstalling, everything works just fine.

Comment: @Chirs seems like i have the same problem here, what's strange is that the exception happens when targeting .NET 4. If i switch to .NET 3.5 then it works.

Comment: .NET 4 apps have the x86 platform target as the default, unlike 3.5 which defaults to AnyCPU.  So the app will read different registry keys on the 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved going into the voices key register and, after a backup of that key, I removed one after one all voices trying the code each time untill the error disappeared. The error was in a Loquendo voice. 
After that I tried to restore the backup (all voices) looking for the error again and... OS answered that a value cannot be written because it was in use by another application... That's the magic thing: all worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Hans Passant pointed us to the fact that this API parses string values from the registry to detect installed languages. I too had a Loquendo TTS language packs installed. Using PROCMON and trial and error, I managed to pinpoint the exact registry key that caused the error (Language). The API expects this string to hold only numeric characters for an integer conversion. Trying to parse and convert this string ("40c") triggers a FormatException:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\LQBernard\Attributes]
"Language"="40c"

changed to:

"Language"="40" (removed the trailing 'c' character).

I repeated this process for both my installed French Loquendo TTS language packs (Bernard and Juliette) and that solved it for me.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I beg to differ. Bob had a FormatException when trying to use the Speech Synthesis API. Hans Passant pointed us to the fact that this API parses string values from the registry to detect installed languages. Bob and I both had Loquendo TTS language packs installed. Using PROCMON and trial and error, I managed to pinpoint the exact registry key that caused the error (Language). Trying to parse and convert to an integer a string that has non-numeric characters triggers a FormatException. CQFD.

Comment: Ok, I'll concede that. But it wasn't clear _how_ this answers the question. If you will edit your answer to include the information you included in the comment, then I'll be able to remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the source of your problem, but it looks like in the API that you should just be able to call

```
new SpeechSynthesizer().Speak("Hello world.");
```

and avoid all the extra code... have you tried removing the period?

Comment: Removing the period doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried a variety of different combinations from complete sentences to simple phrases and it still throws an error.

Comment: It looks like @therealmitchconnors is actually suggesting you remove the `Prompt` class altogether and `Speak` the `string` directly, to see if that's causing the problem.