# SpeechSynthesizer doesn't get all installed voices 2

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have installed a new voice in my Windows 7 32 bits OS in order to be able to use from in one .NET application i'm developing.

But when i use `GetInstalledVoices()` method to view list of all voices, only one (default "Microsoft Anna") appers. Why it may happens?

Voice is appears in Control Panel -> Speech section.

Other TTS applications also can use this voice.

Comment: Check the registry as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10308752/17034  And watch out for the Platform target setting on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Well, I have only Microsoft Anna voice at this path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens". Should I add registry entry manually to be able to use my voice? And how other applications find it?

Comment: Well, that explains it then.  You didn't document whether or not you are running this on a 64-bit version of Windows so no possibly way to help you there.  Contact the vendor of the voices for support.

Comment: I checked this thread before asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208617/speechsynthesizer-doesnt-get-all-installed-voices. I try to run this program on 32-bit version Windows 7. And I compile project to x86 platform target. I also found that at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\TokenEnums\" record about my voice engine exists. "Infovox Desktop v2.2" with parameter "CLSID"="{54B3BC04-C5FE-4262-8A09-9B93EF479F4A}".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538329/acapela-voice-not-detected-in-c-sharp)

This is a bug in `System.Speech.Synthesis` and .NET v4.5 solves this problem.