# C# SpeechSynthesizer GetInstalledVoices - only 2 voices are listed

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I tried to get a list of the installed voices with the code:

```
    using(SpeechSynthesizer synth = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        var installedVoices = synth.GetInstalledVoices();
    }
```

But the returend list contains only 2 items. One for each installed language, both female.
In the Windows control panel however, I can see 3 voices alone for the German language. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51811901/14171304

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong - it's a Speech API implementation flaw. Long story short - there're two sets of voices registered in the system (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices and HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech_OneCore\Voices) but the Speech API only recognizes the first one, meanwhile, technically, it can be used for both.

Find [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71198211/786055) for details and solution options.