# VB.NET GetInstalledVoices fails only for x86, not for AnyCPU

Tags: vb.net, formatexception

I hav the following code:

```
 Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

 Public Class Form1

     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim m_Synth As New SpeechSynthesizer
        For Each v As InstalledVoice In m_Synth.GetInstalledVoices
            Debug.WriteLine(v.VoiceInfo.Name)
        Next

    End Sub
 End Class
```

It stops at

```
        For Each v As InstalledVoice In m_Synth.GetInstalledVoices
```

and gives me the error "System.FormatException".

This is the StackTrace:

bei System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   bei System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   bei System.Speech.Internal.SapiAttributeParser.GetCultureInfoFromLanguageString(String valueString)
   bei System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceInfo..ctor(VoiceObjectToken token)
   bei System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis.BuildInstalledVoices(VoiceSynthesis voiceSynthesizer)
   bei System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis..ctor(WeakReference speechSynthesizer)
   bei System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_VoiceSynthesizer()
   bei System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.GetInstalledVoices()
   bei voice_test.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\kontakt\voice test\voice test\Form1.vb:Zeile 8.

This problem only occurs if I set the project's "Extended Compilation Options" to "Target CPU: x86".
If I set it to "Target CPU: Any CPU", the code runs without any errors and returns the names as expected.
Target framework is ".NET Framework 4". 
I am running Win 7 64 bit.

Does anybody see what might go wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech Synthesizer "Input string was not in a correct format"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304913/speech-synthesizer-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: I don't think so because my problem can be solved by switching from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Comment: That was explicitly discussed in the comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant You only mentioned that "There are possible complications on a 64-bit operating system", right? However, I filed a bug report on MS Connect. If the 64bit version of the framework can read fine from the registry, and the 32bit version can not, there might be a bug, right?

Comment: Sigh, click "show 2 more comments".  It is the last one.  Do not file a bug report on connect, this is a problem with your machine.  Ask for help from a colleague to sort this out if you are not familiar enough with using Regedit.exe

Comment: I have no problem fixing the registry. My problem is that I have like 500 users who will ask me to fix my app because they don't know that Loquendo introduced the bug and not me. With VB6 and Microsoft.Speech everything runs smoothly. Do you understand now why I think the framework is to blame because it is too strict? Loquendo can not be accessed, they are just too lazy.

Comment: @Hans Passant Do you agree with my that the problem seems to be that the framework 32 bit is more strict than the framework 64 bit? Just curious.

Comment: Of course not, the 64 version will throw the exact same exception when the 64-bit registry keys contain junk.  This is a pointless discussion, Microsoft will never commit to accepting garbage in the configuration keys without throwing an exception.  A proper value for the Language key is crucial in voice synthesis.  If you don't like supporting customers then you chose the wrong profession.  I'm done with this question.